# Abbreviation-likes containing spaces

Tags: vimscript, abbreviations

Let's get directly to it.

I was working with some python code and realized I had written a bunch of `elif` blocks as `else if` after working too much in Javascript.

My natural thought was "cool, I can make an abbreviation to fix those for me so I don't have to think much about it". Then I realized {lhs} of abbreviations can't contain spaces.

I could of course abbrev `elif` to `else if` and `:iunab` it for python, but I was wondering if there's a way to fix it if I ever *do* happen to write an `else if` in python. I dug through the `:h ab` files.

`:inoreabbreviate <expr> if f` where f steps back one word and checks if it's an else-if block could work, but I'm wondering if there's any other way that I just don't know of?

Answer (score 3):

This might not be the perfect answer, but I kind of solved the problem by creating the following `augroup`:

```
augroup filetype_python
autocmd!
autocmd BufRead,BufWrite *.py :%s/else if/elif/g
augroup END
```

Basically, it will substitute "**else if**" with "**elif**" (`:%s/else if/elif/g`) whenever a *.*py* file is:

- read    (`BufRead`, e.g `:split testfile.py`) or
- written (`BufWrite`, e.g `:wq` to close save and close the current file)

So, it means that if you suddenly find out that you have been writing "**else if**" you could either write the file with `:w`, or just let it be; whenever you save and close it will be substituted.

Again, this might not be the perfect solution for *you*. It does seems useful for me (I have `<space>` remapped to `:w`, in order to execute the substitution I just hit space).

Anyway thanks for the exercise! (:

Maybe, you could also check Tim Pope's [Vim-abolish](https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish), a plugin that:

> easily search for, substitute, and abbreviate multiple variants of a
>   word

Comment: Good idea! Albeit BufNewFile will never find any text according to spec - it only fires when you open a brand-new file. Those are usually empty.

Comment: Ahaha, thanks for pointing that out. Question edited. Should another event be added?

Comment: Usually it's enough to pretty it up whenever you open or save the file. Technically saving it is enough if you never use other editors, but that's a bit outside scope.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to analyse the context of the text you've typed to know what you want to insert. For instance, you could have a `if` abbreviation that detects there is a `else` just before.

BTW: don't remove abbreviations/mappings for a specific filetype context. Instead define your abbreviations only in a given context with the `<buffer>` specification. And define your abbreviation in filetype plugins (you could play with autocommands, but this doesn't scale).

What you're looking for is something like this:

```
inoreab <buffer> <expr> if repeat("\<bs>", strlen(matchstr(getline('.'), 'else\zs\s*if'))).'if'
```

Note that it doesn't take the current context into account (comments, strings), nor characters other than a space to end the abbreviation. Beside, we can do more like automatically adding semi-colons and jumping to the next line [as I do in lh-brackets](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-brackets/blob/master/ftplugin/python/python_snippets.vim#L42).

Comment: Interesting points, @LucHemitter. But could you provide an example of how `autocommand` would't scale? Thanks in advance. (:

Comment: The more autocommands you have, the more cluttered your .vimrc file becomes. Beside, sharing your configuration would only become possible through copy-pasting. It works as long as you don't have many ft-specific definitions. For instance, for C alone, I have something like [1000 lines of code in my ftplugins](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-cpp/tree/master/ftplugin/c) -- many should be moved to autoload plugins eventually. I can't imagine doing the same thing only with autocommands.

Comment: The idea of defining it globally is that I could then pick up new languages without having to generate a new ftplugin just to put the elif->else if abbrev in there

Comment: We usually know the few languages we are working with. Beside with each we'll want different snippets (code blocks, semantics indenting, ...). PS: I've edited my answer to add a solution to your problem.

Comment: I'm looking it over and this makes a lot of sense, other than repeat not being an editor command; it just multiplies strings for me. Also tested with -u none.

Comment: What do you exactly observe when you type `if` after a `else `?

Comment: E492: Not an editor command: repeat(....
I've tried on several machines, same issue every time. Repeat() is not an editor command.

Comment: No it's not. It's a function meant to be used here in an `iab-<expr>`. You can play with `:echo repeat...` to see what it produces but it won't really help you. Trust the abbreviation and run it -- and don't change anything. For once I've tested it. It does what is intended to do.

Comment: Don't forget the `<expr>`. Don't change the nature of the quote charaters used.  The first time we need to produce backspaces, the second time we yeti to keep the regex simple

Comment: I was sure I had it right - god knows I copied it from your answer and put it into my ftplugins, but it didn't work. Wrote it manually, it worked. I blame windows clipboard.